# validation dialogbox for accidental checkbox checking

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write VBA that will make all of my checkboxes ask whether the user really wants to change the status of the checkbox.

I wrote something like this:

```
Sub ConfirmCheckbox()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to check this box?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Checkbox") = vbYes Then
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).Value = True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

but if somebody wants to uncheck the box because of the previous misclick, he will face the problem where clicking yes ("yes I want to uncheck") will not change anything, where it should uncheck the box.

Also I would like to apply this change to all of my check boxes at once.

I hope this is not that confusing.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Excel doesn't let me go through saying "Compile error: Expected: expression"

Comment: Could you post complete code?
Either it doesn't work or I don't know how to implement it.
I'm working with it for the first time

Comment: I was just trying things I found on the web.  I do not have time to set something up to test myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub ConfirmCheckbox()
    With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change this box?", vbYesNo, _
                                            "Confirm Checkbox") <> vbYes Then
            .Value = IIf(.Value = xlOff, xlOn, xlOff) 'revert the change
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the value of `ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).Value` somewhere and toggle the `boolean` to `true/false` by using `Not`

For some reason I couldn't just go `val = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).Value` so I just added an extra `If Then Else` to set the value

```
Sub ConfirmCheckbox()
    Dim val As Variant
    
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).Value = -4146 Then
        val = True
    Else
        val = False
    End If
    
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to check this box?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Checkbox") = vbYes Then
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).Value = Not val
    Else
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).Value = val
    End If
End Sub
```